# Changing UI from a service

Tags: android, service

I am stuck to the service's tricky being and really need some help. Here I have a method that listens for the chat messages and sends it to the ListAdapter:

```
 @Override
 public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
     Handler mHandler = new Handler();
     Message message = (Message) packet;
     if (message.getBody() != null) {
         String fromName = StringUtils.parseBareAddress(message.getFrom());
         Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity ", " Text Recieved " + message.getBody() + " from " +  fromName);
         messages.add(fromName + ":");
         messages.add(message.getBody());

         // Add the incoming message to the list view
         mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                 setListAdapter();
```

And here is my Listadapter:

```
public static void setListAdapter() {
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listitem, messages);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

I need the chat message-retrieving code to be in an everlasting service, and sends the message to the main activity since a service can not interact with the UI. I know a handler does the job, but as more as I try, I get more confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an event bus like [`Otto`](http://square.github.io/otto/) to deliver updates to your `MainActivity` from the `Service`.

Like kcoppock says, you should persist your messages in a database and use a `ContentObserver` to track changes.

Comment: this looks cool man ! i have asmack library does it work within?

Comment: I do not see why not.

Answer (score 2):

If you go the route of storing your messages in a database, you could also add a `ContentProvider` and have your `Activity` register a `ContentObserver` for changes. Then your `Service` would only have the responsibility of updating the database, and if a UI is visible, it will detect the changes. You could probably end up just doing something with `LocalBroadcastManager` (in the v4 support library) to notify when a new message is received; but you should still be persisting the messages somewhere permanent.

Comment: This is the pattern I was thinking, but the Otto library does look good. The advantage your method has is that it doesn't rely on an external lib.

Comment: You are right about persisting messages somewhere permanent. I used to use `LocalBroadcastmanager` but then you need to add a `BoardcastRecevier` and it is a pain to test. Otto seems to lead to more reusable code.

Comment: Yeah, Otto is nice for this too. I'd probably use that instead of LocalBroadcastManager if you go that route, but I think the database is the proper solution (although definitely a non-trivial amount of work to implement!)

Comment: yes that is my laters plan to route a database for keeping chatmessages, every comment was a hope light for me, wish could accept both , thanks alot guys <3